# Unable to connect to my database server using the provided settings

Tags: php, codeigniter, database-connection

I got this error after i created my DB "Unable to connect to my database server using the provided settings"

Here is code....

```
 * Database Loader

public function database($params = '', $return = FALSE, $active_record = NULL)
{
    // Grab the super object
    $CI =& get_instance();

    // Do we even need to load the database class?
    if (class_exists('CI_DB') AND $return == FALSE AND $active_record == NULL AND isset($CI->db) AND is_object($CI->db))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    require_once(BASEPATH.'database/DB.php');

    if ($return === TRUE)
    {
        return DB($params, $active_record);
    }

    // Initialize the db variable.  Needed to prevent
    // reference errors with some configurations
    $CI->db = '';

    // Load the DB class
    $CI->db =& DB($params, $active_record);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually doesn't have anything to do with your code. Your application can't connect to the database using the provided database settings: (Host, username, and password).
Ensure that you have a database with the correct name and have a Database user setup with access privileges to that database.
The config file is typically located at `application/config/database.php`.

Comment: when i run on localhost everything is fine.

Comment: @user2184809 when you mean localhost are you meaning the remote server or your computer?

Comment: @user2184809 Just because it will work on your localhost doesn't mean you have the database and db user setup on your remote machine.

Comment: on the server i already created DB n DB user setup but it does not work.

Comment: is there any other option where i can fix?

Comment: @user2184809 it's simply a matter of getting your database connection information in your database config file to match the database and user you have created.

Comment: i already config the DB name n uer to match the DB n user i have created but still i can connect to the DB.

Comment: @user2184809 The error being shown is telling you the information does not match. We don't have anything else to go on. This is not a code error, it's a configuration issue between what is in your database configuration file and the database you're attempting to connect to. If you can't figure it out, contact your hosting provider for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally find a solution for I think is the same problem that you're having, it's due to the php version that you have at your server, in my case I have php 5.3.5 in my localhost but in my server I had php 5.2.6 I wasn't go further but the main problem was the avoiding notification when a function doesn´t work properly, specifically in "mysql_driver.php"
line 150.

```
return @mysql_set_charset($charset, $this->conn_id);
```

get rid of "@", to see the real problem, I found this, stopping each certain part of my script till I finally found where was the problem.
to solve this you can set "$this->use_set_names" to true, so that you can use the if condition near to the line I've pointed out to you.
If the problem wasn't this, probably is something similar, you can test each part of your script (debugging).

Comment: Now that I see, I think your problem is related to your $db configuration, maybe you're missing some param, but my advice can help someone who is having a similar problem as I've described above.